# Change button's background from inside element on listview, Android

Tags: android

I have a `ListView lv`, and i have a `Button delete` at the bottom of the Listview (the button is outside of the listview). There is a problem that how i can deal with the button (such as change background or set text for the button) from inside the listview. I have my own adapter, and i think that i have to handle the button's changing at the `public void getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` function. Does anyone have any idea?
P/s: the main point of this question is: "How to deal with other elements from inside a list view?".
Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: using **findViewById** get that view and change it.. whats the problem..

Comment: how? In `myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter` i can't using findViewById! This function only work in Activity!

Comment: Somwhere you will create an instance of this from an ACtivity.. pass Activity instance in its contructer and use it..

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpful! Sorry for my stupid question, because i'm pretty new in android :D!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the activity ,

```
Button delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(delete);//add your argumente here
```

Now in the adapter you can set OnClickListener for the button.

Comment: Yeah, i just do like you said, it's very helpful! Thank you so much :D!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't just save a reference to the Button from the `Activity` or `Fragment`'s `onCreate` method, then inside `getView` you would need to implement a loop that walks up the `ViewParent` chain searching for the actual view you want. It could look something like this:

```
ViewParent nv = parent.getParent();
while(nv != null){
  if(View.class.isInstance(nv)){
    View button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
    if(button != null){
      // FOUND IT!
      // do something, then break;
      break;
    }
  }
  nv = nv.getParent();
}
```

Didn't compile or test that, but...something like that should do what you want. See the [`ViewParent.getParent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#getParent%28%29) docs for the details.

Comment: This works .. Except that you cannot call findViewById directly in the adapter. You need an object of View for that. View button = ((View) nv).findViewById(R.id.button_id); should be used in place of findViewById.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are using a custom arrayadapter. If so you could pass a reference to the button to the arrayadapter class.

I am not sure if this will let you edit the button though. If not you could send the ArrayAdapter a handler from the Activity. So in the activity create a handler with something like this:

```
    protected Handler updateButtonHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        //Update button
    }
};
```

And then in the arrayadapter have a reference and:

```
updateButtonHandler.sendEmptyMsg(0);
```